# Want to delete all lines from a file but keep last 50000 lines

Tags: shell, unix

I have a huge file which has lots of lines. File system got full.

I want your help guys, to suggest me a solution so that I can remove all lines from that file but not last 50000 lines. I want solution which can remove lines from existing file so that I can have some space left with.

Comment: Count the amount of lines in your file, then determine where the 50.000th but last line starts and read-and-write that to a new file. Please note that it *has* to be a new file and please note that you therefore should have enough storage space to store such a file before you delete the original file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tail` for this:

```
tail -n 50000 file > new_file
```

or even

```
tail -50000 file > new_file
```

To save the output in the same file you can do:

```
tail -n 50000 file > new_file && mv new_file file
```

Which will save the output in a temporary file that will replace the original in case `tail` command perform correctly.

---

From `man tail`:

> tail - output the last part of files
>
> **-n, --lines=K**
>
> output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to
>   output lines starting with the Kth

Comment: Except that this won't work on an already-full filesystem. :(

Comment: What about outputting the file to another filesystem? It should make it, and it is quite normal for a server to have more than one.

Comment: That would work, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` you could say:

```
sed -e :a -e '$q;N;50001,$D;ba' filename
```

If you want to modify the file in-place, say:

```
sed -i -e :a -e '$q;N;50001,$D;ba' filename
```